# SharePoint Designer 2013 download from local server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

With SharePoint 2010 whenever you wanted to edit a file in SharePoint Designer 2010, the installation file of SharePoint Designer 2010 is downloaded from the local server. But with SharePoint 2013 when you click "Edit in Sharepoint Designer" you get directed to the Microsoft web site to download the installation package.

How will I be able to download the installation from our local server instead of downloading it from the Microsoft website everytime?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SharePoint Designer does not ship with the Installation Media for SharePoint Server 2013.

I looked at all the .msi files in the media and none are for SPD. Also there is no SPDESIGN.exe anywhere on my SharePoint server.

Perhaps you can drop the installation files on SharePoint when someone needs to use it, or leave it in a share.